# how convert response object property from array in to request rxjs

Tags: typescript, rxjs

API returns an array of JSON Objects.

```
[
{
    "vacancy": "61a6597b0dc105d6e79a1f30",
    "createdBy": "61aa11644afa183fa28b0792",
    "executor": "61aa20ee25ef06b69920a505",
    "reviewer": "61aa11644afa183fa28b0792",
    "status": "Invited",
    "_id": "61aa213aeaf2af804aa1e591",
    "createdAt": "2021-12-03T13:52:58.772Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-12-03T13:52:58.772Z"
},
...
]
```

And I need convert some propertys in to objects by making get request with value.
Something like that:

```
this.http.get<Application>(
      `${environment.API_ENDPOINT}/applications/assigned?status=completed`
    ).pipe(
        map(aplication => 
{
...aplication,
vacancy:this.http.get(`${environment.API_ENDPOINT}/vacancys/`+ aplication.vacancy),
executor:this.http.get(`${environment.API_ENDPOINT}/candidates/`+ aplication.executor)
}
    )
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a "[Higher Order Mapping Operator](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)", which will internally subscribe to an observable and emit its emissions.

In your case, [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) will work for this.  Since you need to make two different calls, we can use [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) to create an observable that will emit both results when they are received:

```js
myObj$ = this.http.get<Application>('/applications/assigned').pipe(
    switchMap(aplication => forkJoin({
        vacancy  : this.http.get(`environment.API_ENDPOINT}/vacancys/${vacancy}`),
        executor : this.http.get(`environment.API_ENDPOINT}/candidates/${executor}`)
    }).pipe(
        map(({vacancy, executor}) => ({...aplication, vacancy, executor})
    ))
);
```